# How to find the limit of the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{4 x_n -3}\,$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, recurrence-relations

Consider the sequence ($x_n$) defined by $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{4 x_n -3}$, for $n \geq 1$ and $x_1 = 7$.

I know how to show  $x_n$ is monotone decreasing and bounded (by induction). But I don't know how to find its limit.

When I solve $L^2 = 4L-3$, it gives me $L=1, 3$; I don't know how to delete $L=1$.

Comment: What bound did you get by induction?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Either 1 or 3 can get the desired the lower bound. So we can prove the limit exists.

Comment: If you assume $x_n$>1, then 1 will be your lower bound. If you assume $x_n$>3, then 3 will be your lower bound.

Comment: So you're saying you can prove that $x_n>3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This means the limit can't be $1$.

Comment: I observe that the derivative of $\sqrt{4x-3}$ is greater than $1$ on an open neighborhood of $x = 1$, so $1$ is a repelling fixed point.  The only sequence of iterates that remains in a neighborhood of $1$ on repeated iteration is the constantly $1$ sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $x_n \gt 3, x_{n+1} \gt 3$ so your entire sequence is bounded below by $3$.

Comment: yes, I know this. But how to exclude 1 is not limit?

Comment: Because $x_n>3$.

Comment: @Mariana If $x_n>3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_n\to L$ then $L\geq 3$.